# Where is the white space coming from?

Tags: html, css

I have a large chunk of white space that I cant seem to remove from the website I am working on and its driving me nuts. Its right at the top of the page.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
}
#main-header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5% 0.5% 0.5% 4%;
}
#main-header nav {} nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header id="main-header">
      <h1>DEdesigns</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- end header -->
    <article id="about-me">
      <header>
        <h2>About Me</h2>
      </header>
      <section>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged</p>
      </section>
      <aside>
        <figure>
          <img src="#" alt="#" width="#" height="#">
        </figure>
      </aside>
    </article>
    <!-- end #about-me -->
    <div id="gallery">
      <header>
        <h2>My Work</h2>
      </header>
      <div id="gallery-conatiner">
        <figure>
          <img src="#" alt="#" width="#" height="#">
        </figure>
        <section>
          <aside>
            <p>rem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500</p>
          </aside>
        </section>
        <!--  ends first row -->
        <section>
          <aside>
            <p>rem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500</p>
          </aside>
        </section>
        <figure>
          <img src="#" alt="#" width="#" height="#">
        </figure>
        <!-- ends second row -->
        <figure>
          <img src="#" alt="#" width="#" height="#">
        </figure>
        <aside>
          <p>rem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500</p>
        </aside>
        </section>
        <!-- ends third row -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #gallery -->
    <article id="services">
      <header>
        <h2>Services</h2>
      </header>
      <section>
        <ol>
          <li>one</li>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
        </ol>
      </section>
    </article>
    <!-- end #services -->
    <article id="contact-me">
      <header>
        <h2>Contact Me</h2>
      </header>
      <p>some contact me stuff goes here</p>
    </article>
    <!-- end #contact-me -->
    <footer>
      <p>This is my fotter</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- end #container -->
</body>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Add `top: 0` to `#main-header`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
}
#main-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5% 0.5% 0.5% 4%;
}
#main-header nav {} nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
#about-me {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 39px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header id="main-header">
      <h1>DEdesigns</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- end header -->
    <article id="about-me">
      <header>
        <h2>About Me</h2>
      </header>
      <section>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged</p>
      </section>
      <aside>
        <figure>
          <img src="#" alt="#" width="#" height="#">
        </figure>
      </aside>
    </article>
    <!-- end #about-me -->
    <div id="gallery">
      <header>
        <h2>My Work</h2>
      </header>
      <div id="gallery-conatiner">
        <figure>
          <img src="#" alt="#" width="#" height="#">
        </figure>
        <section>
          <aside>
            <p>rem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500</p>
          </aside>
        </section>
        <!--  ends first row -->
        <section>
          <aside>
            <p>rem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500</p>
          </aside>
        </section>
        <figure>
          <img src="#" alt="#" width="#" height="#">
        </figure>
        <!-- ends second row -->
        <figure>
          <img src="#" alt="#" width="#" height="#">
        </figure>
        <aside>
          <p>rem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500</p>
        </aside>
        </section>
        <!-- ends third row -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #gallery -->
    <article id="services">
      <header>
        <h2>Services</h2>
      </header>
      <section>
        <ol>
          <li>one</li>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
        </ol>
      </section>
    </article>
    <!-- end #services -->
    <article id="contact-me">
      <header>
        <h2>Contact Me</h2>
      </header>
      <p>some contact me stuff goes here</p>
    </article>
    <!-- end #contact-me -->
    <footer>
      <p>This is my fotter</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- end #container -->
</body>
```

Comment: @DEdesigns57 – Because if you don't specify a `top` or `left` when flopping `position` to `absolute` or `fixed`, the element will display where it originally appeared in the document flow.

Comment: You should keep in mind, that this will still cut of the top of your content. So you need an extra `margin` or `padding` for the top of the container. I suggested an edit in the answer above.

Comment: I have tried adding margin 0 to the container, body and even the html element itself. I still have that white space at the top, how can I remove it?

Comment: I have found it in header h2. Thats where the margin was comming from!